# Prove that every sequence in the minimal uncountable well-ordered set is bounded above.

Tags: general-topology, proof-verification

Let $\Omega$ denote the minimal uncountable well-ordered set. We are trying to prove that every sequence $\{x_n\} \subset \Omega$ is bounded above. To begin, assume to the contrary that such an unbounded sequence $(x_n)$ is indeed fully contained in $\Omega$. $S_{x_n}$, the section of $x_n$, is countable for any $n$ by definition of $\Omega$. Then the union of all such $(x_n)$ is countable, as it is just a countable union of countable sets. To prove a contradiction, we show that $\cup S_{x_n} = \Omega$. Forward set inclusion is trivial, as $S_{x_n} \subset \Omega$ for all $n$ by assumption. In the reverse direction, for any $y \in \Omega$, there exists a $N$ such that $y \in S_{x_N}$ since $(x_n)$ is not bounded above. Therefore, $\Omega \subset \cup S_{x_n}$ and we've shown the sets are equal. However, $\Omega$ is uncountable by definition while $\cup S_{x_n}$ is countable, so we've a contradiction.

Is this proof correct?

Comment: This seems fine. I'd rather phrase it as saying that if $y$ were not in some section, then it would be an upper bound, and your way of phrasing it just sounded like "this is true because I said so."

Comment: The proof rather depends on your set theory set up. I'd say, a countable union of countable ordinals is an ordinal (as a union of ordinals is one) and still countable, so  an element of $\omega_1$ by definition, and is the required upperbound.  This would work nicely for the Neumann definition of ordinal, but maybe not the way it's set up in your text.

Comment: I assume a section of $x$ means either  $\{y: y\le x \}$ or $\{y:y<x\}$. The latter  has also been called an  initial segment and  denoted by $pred(x)$. ("Predecessors")... I think it would be simpler to say that if the union of the sequence of sections had no upper bound then $\cup_n(x_n) =\Omega,$ which would make $\Omega$ countable......+1

Comment: Thank you everyone for your feedback.